# Pagination with spring data JPA

Tags: java, spring, api, rest, spring-data

I hava to do a pagination request in this GET but I'm not getting it.

```
@GetMapping(value = {"uf/{uf}"})
    public List<Cidade> findByUF(@PathVariable String uf, Pageable page){
         return repositorioCidade.findByUF(uf);        
    }
```

Repository:

```
public interface RepositorioCidade extends JpaRepository<Cidade,Long>{
    @Query(nativeQuery= true, value="SELECT * FROM cidade WHERE uf = ?")
    List<Cidade> findByUF(String uf);
    @Query(nativeQuery= true, value="SELECT * FROM cidade WHERE cidade = ?")
    List<Cidade> findByNome(String nome);
    @Query(nativeQuery= true, value="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cidade")
    List<Cidade> countRegistros(String cidade);
}
```

Comment: Spring Data will create the queries for you if you name them correctly, and you should avoid using `nativeQuery` whenever possible. (Also, `count` should return `long`, not `List`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of method queries. In your repository add the following method query:

```
public interface RepositorioCidade extends JpaRepository<Cidade,Long> {

    Page<Cidade> findByUf(String uf, Pageable pageable);

}
```

And change your controller to this:

```
@GetMapping(value = {"uf/{uf}"})
public Page<Cidade> findByUF(@PathVariable String uf, Pageable pageable){
     return repositorioCidade.findByUf(uf, pageable);        
}
```